# Rails model validation - undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i'm trying to validate the presence on a parameter in rails. this is the code snippet for `User.rb`

```
  validates :terms_of_service, presence: true 
  validates :privacy_policy, presence: true
```

Ideally , i would like rails to throw an error if this parameter is not present

here is a sample parameter list sent by the client

```
Parameters: {"username"=>"f", "email"=>"f@f.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "confirm_success_url"=>"http://localhost:4000", "config_name"=>"default", "registration"=>{"username"=>"f", "email"=>"f@f.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "confirm_success_url"=>"http://localhost:4000"}}
```

However, rails throws the below error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `terms_of_service' for #<User:0x007f16d402e788>):
```

why does it think that there should be a `terms_of_service` method when i'm actually testing a parameter?

Comment: `terms_of_service` is a parameter corresponding to a column at Users table and ActiveModel creates a method to retrive its value. This is automatic and if is not there, maybe the column is not there either. Please post your `db/schema.rb`.

Comment: Ah i see, wasnt aware that there needs to be a corresponding column in the db. I was just hoping to ensure that both parameters (tos and privacy) are true before saving the user to the table. If i dont want a column , i'm assuming i have to use a before_commit hook in the models table and ensure the params exist?

Comment: or you can create terms_of_service as an attr_accessor.

Comment: It doesn't need to be backed by a column. This is just the most common case. But the answer poated gives you another option. Try it and check if it does what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `attr_accessor`, it will set a getter and setter method and validation will work on it even if it is a non column attribute

```
attr_accessor :terms_of_service
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: whilte i'm able to access the params using attr_accessor , `validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: true` always seems to fail regardless of the values sent (false,true or no key present). is this again related to not having a column in the table?

Comment: You need to add `attr_accessor` for non-column attributes.